# Hiding and showing button on click in twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html, onclick

I have the following jQuery and css that I've used previously and worked, however in the new solution (which is a copy of the existing one) this does not work:

```
                <script>

                    $("#inprogress_btn").click(function () {
                        if (!($("#inprogress_btn").is(":visible"))) {
                            $("#onhold_btn").show();
                            $("#inprogress_btn").hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#onhold_btn").hide();
                            $("#inprogress_btn").show();
                        }
                    })
                </script>

        <button style="margin-top:50px;" id="onhold_btn" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">On Hold</button>
        <button id="inprogress_btn" class="btn btn-block btn-success">In Progress</button>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that it is not working? It is hiding the button according to your code.

Comment: If both buttons are in view, check for conflicts of id's and/or classes.

Answer (score 0):

it worked, please checkout [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paul_cheung/6yp47/), it reference  jQuery 1.10.1, hope helps.

```
$(function(){
    $("#inprogress_btn").click(function () {
               if (!($("#inprogress_btn").is(":visible"))) {
                    $("#onhold_btn").show();
                    $("#inprogress_btn").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#onhold_btn").hide();
                    $("#inprogress_btn").show();
                }
            });
})
```